# Repeating ID based on

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a very simple requirement but I'm struggling to find a way around this.

I have a very simple query:

```
SELECT
  ServiceCode,
  StartDate,
  Available,
  Nights,
  BookingID
FROM @tmpAvailability
LEFT JOIN vwRSBooking B 
  ON B.Depart = A.StartDate 
 AND B.ServiceCode = A.SupplierCode 
 AND B.StatusID IN (2640, 2621)
ORDER BY StartDate;
```

Made up of 2 tables
@tmpAvailability which consists of the following fields:

- SupplierCode
- StartDate
- Available

vwRSBooking which consists of the following fields

- BookingID
- DepartDate
- Code
- Nights
- StatusID

Departure and startdate can be joined to link the first day, and the servicecode and suppliercode can be joined to make sure that the availability is linked to the same supplier.

Which produces an output like this:

```
Code    |    Dates    |    Available  |  Nights | BookingID
TEST    | 2018-01-04  |        1      |  NULL   | NULL
TEST    | 2018-01-05  |        1      |  NULL   | NULL
TEST    | 2018-01-06  |        0      |  4      | 123456
TEST    | 2018-01-07  |        0      |  NULL   | NULL
TEST    | 2018-01-08  |        0      |  NULL   | NULL
TEST    | 2018-01-09  |        0      |  NULL   | NULL
TEST    | 2018-01-10  |        1      |  NULL   | NULL
TEST    | 2018-01-11  |        1      |  NULL   | NULL
TEST    | 2018-01-12  |        1      |  NULL   | NULL
TEST    | 2018-01-13  |        0      |  NULL   | 234567
TEST    | 2018-01-14  |        0      |  NULL   | NULL
TEST    | 2018-01-15  |        0      |  NULL   | NULL
```

What I need is when the BookingID in for 4 days that the bookingID and the nights are spread across those days, for example:

```
Code    |    Dates    |    Available  |  Nights | BookingID
TEST    | 2018-01-04  |        1      |  NULL   | NULL
TEST    | 2018-01-05  |        1      |  NULL   | NULL
TEST    | 2018-01-06  |        0      |  4      | 123456
TEST    | 2018-01-07  |        0      |  4      | 123456
TEST    | 2018-01-08  |        0      |  4      | 123456
TEST    | 2018-01-09  |        0      |  4      | 123456
TEST    | 2018-01-10  |        1      |  NULL   | NULL
TEST    | 2018-01-11  |        1      |  NULL   | NULL
TEST    | 2018-01-12  |        1      |  NULL   | NULL
TEST    | 2018-01-13  |        0      |  3      | 234567
TEST    | 2018-01-14  |        0      |  3      | 234567
TEST    | 2018-01-15  |        0      |  3      | 234567
TEST    | 2018-01-16  |        1      |  NULL   | NULL
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to solve it would be most appreciated.

Andrew

Comment: Where does the "3" come from in your desired output?  What if the 3 followed the 4 and there were not enough nights in-between?

Comment: I suspect that in the first query results 2018-01-13 should have a 3 in the Nights column...

Comment: Can you share with us the structure of `vwRSBooking`?

Comment: Correct sorry, I've added it in now. Nights is the duration that the holiday is from. So if the date is 2018-01-06 and then nights is 4 the bookingID needs to be repeated until the 2018-01-09.

Comment: vwRSBooking has the format: `BookingID, Nights, Depart, Code`

Comment: In your case it is better to provide sample data from two tables, not result of the query

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've updated, hopefully makes things a little clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace your `vwRSBooking` with another view which uses a CTE to obtain all the dates the booking covers. Then use the view's `coverdate` for joining to the `@tmpAvailability` table:

```
CREATE VIEW vwRSBookingFull
AS
    WITH cte ( bookingid, nights, depart, code, coverdate)
         AS (SELECT bookingid,
                    nights,
                    depart,
                    code,
                    depart
               FROM vwRSBooking

             UNION ALL
             SELECT c.bookingid,
                    c.nights,
                    c.depart,
                    c.code,
                    DATEADD(d, 1, c.coverdate)
               FROM cte c
              WHERE DATEDIFF(d, c.depart, c.coverdate) < (c.nights - 1))
    SELECT c.bookingid,
           c.nights,
           c.depart,
           c.code,
           c.coverdate
      FROM cte c

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a calendar table with all the dates in the date range your dates may fall into. For this example, I build one for January 2018. We can then join onto this table to create the additional rows.

Here is the sample code I used. You can see it at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/08cf1/1/0).

```
CREATE TABLE code (
  code varchar(max),
  dates date,
  available int,
  nights int,
  bookingid int
  )

INSERT INTO code VALUES
('TEST','2018-01-04','1',NULL,NULL),
('TEST','2018-01-05','1',NULL,NULL),
('TEST','2018-01-06','0',4,123456),
('TEST','2018-01-07','0',NULL,NULL),
('TEST','2018-01-08','0',NULL,NULL),
('TEST','2018-01-09','0',NULL,NULL),
('TEST','2018-01-10','1',NULL,NULL),
('TEST','2018-01-11','1',NULL,NULL),
('TEST','2018-01-12','1',NULL,NULL),
('TEST','2018-01-13','0',3,234567),
('TEST','2018-01-14','0',NULL,NULL),
('TEST','2018-01-15','0',NULL,NULL)

CREATE TABLE dates (
  dates date
  )
INSERT INTO dates VALUES
('2018-01-01'),('2018-01-02'),('2018-01-03'),('2018-01-04'),('2018-01-05'),('2018-01-06'),('2018-01-07'),('2018-01-08'),('2018-01-09'),('2018-01-10'),('2018-01-11'),('2018-01-12'),('2018-01-13'),('2018-01-14'),('2018-01-15'),('2018-01-16'),('2018-01-17'),('2018-01-18'),('2018-01-19'),('2018-01-20'),('2018-01-21'),('2018-01-22'),('2018-01-23'),('2018-01-24'),('2018-01-25'),('2018-01-26'),('2018-01-27'),('2018-01-28'),('2018-01-29'),('2018-01-30'),('2018-01-31')
```

Here is the query based on this dataset:

```
SELECT
  code.code,
  dates.dates,
  code.available,
  code.nights,
  code.bookingid
FROM code
LEFT JOIN dates ON
  dates.dates >= code.dates
  AND dates.dates < DATEADD(DAY,nights,code.dates)
```

Edit: Here is an example using your initial query as a subquery to join your result set onto the dates table if you want a copy & paste. Still requires creating the dates table.

```
SELECT
  ServiceCode,
  StartDate,
  Available,
  Nights,
  BookingID
FROM (
  SELECT
    ServiceCode,
    StartDate,
    Available,
    Nights,
    BookingID
  FROM @tmpAvailability
  LEFT JOIN vwRSBooking B 
    ON B.Depart = A.StartDate 
    AND B.ServiceCode = A.SupplierCode 
    AND B.StatusID IN (2640, 2621)
  ) code
LEFT JOIN dates ON
  dates.dates >= code.dates
  AND dates.dates < DATEADD(DAY,nights,code.dates)
ORDER BY StartDate;
```